# Find whether a 32-bit integer is a power of 2 using bitwise operators

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, machine-code

I need to implement this without using subtraction or addition (purely bitwise operators). The algorithm ((num - 1) & num) == 0 doesn't work for me because it uses subtraction. I need to be able to do this in just one line of code so I'm looking for any hint as to how to do this using only bitwise operators.

Comment: Check for num>0&&(num&(num-1))

Comment: why do you need to do this?

Comment: @RishabhJain I cannot use subtraction otherwise I would simply use that... I can only use bitwise operators.

Comment: By your reference to machine code, do you have a popcount instruction that you are allowed to use?  You could then compare its result to 1.  (Though "compare" is usually a subtraction under the hood...)

Comment: Your restriction of no addition or subtraction is rather bizarre.  Does it have a real-life explanation, or is it an artificial restriction coming from an assignment / coding challenge / interview question / etc?

Comment: @NateEldredge It is just an artificial restriction from a class assignment.

Comment: On `x86` I would use `BSR ECX,EAX`, `BSF EDX,EAX`, `CMP ECX,EDX`. It returns `ZF` when `EAX` is power of two.

Comment: @Money Mit - You forgot to specify (a) what you consider as _bitwise operators_, and (b) the language of the _code_.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.